# Getting Profile Data Null when Sign In With Google

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-plus, google-authentication

I have Integrated "Login with Google". Code is here

```
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestEmail()
                .requestProfile()
                .build();
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
                .enableAutoManage(this,this)
                .build();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        final Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);



 public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
            if (result.isSuccess()) {
                GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();
                String tokenId = acct.getIdToken();
                name = acct.getDisplayName();
                String personGivenName = acct.getGivenName();
                String personFamilyName = acct.getFamilyName();
                email = acct.getEmail();
                social_id = acct.getId();
                social_image = String.valueOf(acct.getPhotoUrl());
                Log.w("googleres", name + "," + personGivenName + "," + personFamilyName + "," + email + "," + social_id + "," + social_image);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "failed to login with google", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        }
    }
```

When I'm going to login with new account first time I'm getting this response in log

```
W/googleres: null,null,null,test@gmail.com,123456669985545,null
```

name and display picture getting null and when doing login

second time getting all data perfectly.

Comment: What do you mean by second time? You logout, then back in?

Comment: @ cricket_007 yes, when i logged In second time.

Comment: You may want to check this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/sign-in) which discussed how to properly configure Google Sign-in. Also, start sign-in flow wherein intent prompts the user to select a Google account to sign in with then check scopes. As mentioned in the given link, if you requested scopes beyond profile, email, and openid, the user is also prompted to grant access to the requested resources.

Comment: @Teyam As you can see in code I have configured properly. If there is any configuration issue then  it should not work second time too.

Comment: Have you got any solution?